# While slowing routine down

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a while loop that seems to be slowing my code down. When I run the code provided, it takes a long time without printing anything, then runs around 30 times really fast, and then stops running again.

If i run the query without the while, it quite fast, while if i try to run iterations, it happens what is described above.

```
--LOOP
DECLARE @i int = 1

While @i <= 5

--(SELECT COUNT(*)
--                  FROM Pedido)

BEGIN


SELECT 1


--DECLARE @i int = 1
--Temporary table with stock number
IF object_id ('tempdb..#ESTOQUE_UPDATE') is not null DROP TABLE #ESTOQUE_UPDATE
SELECT DISTINCT 
    P.Item
    ,(Qtd_Estoques - Qtd_Pedida) AS Qtd_Estoques
INTO 
    #ESTOQUE_UPDATE
    FROM #PEDIDO_RN W
    INNER JOIN Pedido P
        ON W.Pedido = P.Pedido
    INNER JOIN Estoque E
        ON P.Item = E.Item
    where 
        W.Id = 1


SET @i = @i+1
END
```

EDIT 1
I'm adding the whole code to show why I'm using the loop

```
--SELECT *
--  FROM Pedido P
--  INNER JOIN Estoque E
--  ON P.Item = E.Item
--  ORDER BY P.Prioridade_Calc ASC

DROP TABLE Pedidos_completos
CREATE TABLE Pedidos_completos
(
    Pedido VarChar(MAX)
)

-- Bota em ordem os pedidos e coloca na table temporária #PEDIDO_RN

IF object_id ('tempdb..#PEDIDO_RN') is not null DROP TABLE #PEDIDO_RN
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Prioridade_Calc) AS Id
    ,P.Prioridade_Calc
    ,P.Pedido
INTO #PEDIDO_RN
    FROM
    Pedido P
    GROUP BY P.Prioridade_Calc , P.Pedido
    ORDER BY P.Prioridade_Calc


SELECT * FROM #PEDIDO_RN
    ORDER BY Id


--LOOP
DECLARE @i int = 1

While @i <= SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM Pedido

BEGIN


--Tabela temporaria com o novo número de estoque
IF object_id ('tempdb..#ESTOQUE_UPDATE') is not null DROP TABLE #ESTOQUE_UPDATE
SELECT DISTINCT 
    P.Item
    ,(Qtd_Estoques - Qtd_Pedida) AS Qtd_Estoques
INTO 
    #ESTOQUE_UPDATE
    FROM #PEDIDO_RN W
    INNER JOIN Pedido P
        ON W.Pedido = P.Pedido
    INNER JOIN Estoque E
        ON P.Item = E.Item
    where 
        W.Id = @i

SELECT * FROM #ESTOQUE_UPDATE   
--Verifica se não existem negativos
DECLARE @flag int
            SET @flag = CASE 
                WHEN (SELECT MIN (E.Qtd_Estoques)
                    FROM #ESTOQUE_UPDATE E) < 0 
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END


--Atualiza a tablea de estoque
IF @flag = 1
    BEGIN
    UPDATE E
        SET
            E.Qtd_Estoques = U.Qtd_Estoques
        FROM Estoque E
            INNER JOIN #ESTOQUE_UPDATE U
            ON E.Item = U.Item
    END


--Adiciona pedidos dem pedidos completos    
IF @flag = 1 
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO Pedidos_completos 
                SELECT 
                    Pedido
                FROM    #PEDIDO_RN

        WHERE Id = @i
        END

SET @i = @i+1

END


SELECT * FROM Pedidos_completos
SELECT * FROM #ESTOQUE_UPDATE
SELECT * FROM Estoque
```

And below the Tables structure

```
CREATE TABLE Pedido 
(
    Pedido VarChar(MAX)
    ,Produto VarChar(MAX)
    ,Item VarChar(MAX)
    ,Prioridade_Calc VarChar(MAX)
    ,Valor_Total_Pedido VarChar(MAX)
    ,Qtd_Pedida VarChar(MAX)
    ,Aglutinacao_Calc VarChar(MAX)
    ,Valor_Minimo VarChar(MAX)

)

ALTER TABLE Pedido
    ALTER COLUMN Valor_Total_Pedido float

ALTER TABLE Pedido
    ALTER COLUMN Valor_Minimo   float

ALTER TABLE Pedido
    ALTER COLUMN Qtd_Pedida   int


ALTER TABLE Pedido
    ALTER COLUMN Prioridade_Calc   int



CREATE TABLE Estoque
(
    Item VarChar(MAX)
    ,Qtd_Estoques VarChar(MAX)

)

ALTER TABLE Estoque
    ALTER COLUMN Qtd_Estoques int
```

Comment: SQL Server isn't a programming language, it's an RDBMS. It excels at Set Based operations, not iterative ones, and a `WHILE` is an iterative task. In short: yes, a `WHILE` will slow your query down, as SQL Server is awful at doing a `WHILE`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here, as, by the looks of it, you're simply trying to `INSERT` the same dataset into `#ESTOQUE_UPDATE` 5 times.

Comment: Something here doesn't add up. You are dropping and recreating the exact same temp table multiple times. And you haven't actually asked a question. You simply stated the obvious, that when you run a while loop your code slows down. Did you have a question or need help with something?

Comment: You mentioned printing.  SQL Server batches it's print commands, so it's not representative of when the command actually finished.  As @Larnu mentioned, it's not intended to use loops.  But if you have to use it, you can have it write to the Messages window immediately using: 
RAISERROR ('Immediate message', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT

Comment: Your code doesn't PRINT anything, and what do you mean it runs "30 times really fast"?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mention this is just part of the code. I am running this just to check how fast it runs with the WHILE loop. I am aware that I shouldn't use loops but I couldn't find a way do what I want without it.

Comment: My problem is: I have bunch of queries inside the WHILE loop. When I run them individually, they all run instantly. When I add them in the while loop with 5 iterations, however, the code takes a whole minute to run.

Comment: What is the purpose of the WHILE loop?  Are you changing values in a variable to get different results?  Your code above is showing the exact same code overwriting the exact same temp table.  Can you post the entire code and some DDL code showing your table/index structure?

Comment: I addes some more code for you guys to understand what I'm trying to do. This is essentially my first code in SQL, so there might be a way better way to do this!